# Microsoft Dynamics SL window opens minimized. Must hit ALT + Spacebar and then maximize

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-sl

We currently use microsoft dynamics sl. It is a miserable program but there are two reports that when you click on them they open minimized. you have to hit alt+spacebar and then select maximize to see the screen. If you drag the screen or move it, it freaks out and no longer works. What is really odd, this same screen will sometimes open normally for other SL users on the same computer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a user customization on the screen.  You could try to remove the user customization by deleting it via SQL.  Run against the system (not company DB).

Delete from customvba where entityid = 'USERNAME'